# Multimap insertion crashes after 1 insert

Tags: c++, insert, crash, multimap

I am writing a program that is a spellchecker, which implements a crude version(for simplicity) of soundexing an incorrectly spelled word.

GOAL: While iterating a SET, which holds all the words in a dictionary, a soundex code is generated, then inserted into a Multimap with the soundex being the key, and the word from the dictionary being the associated data.

ISSUE: After the For loop iterates once, the program crashes. I have narrowed it down to the issue being the actual insertion itself.

NOTE:   d is a pointer which holds my Multimap.
 my multimap is sndxMap;

CODE:

```
ReplacementChooser::ReplacementChooser(const Dictionaries& dictionary)
{

//loop through the dictionary, giving the word to extendedsoundex
for(Dictionaries::iterator it = dictionary.begin(); it!=dictionary.end();it++)
  {  
     string code = extendedSoundex(*it,-1);

      d->sndxMap.insert(multimap<string,string>::value_type(code,*it));   //crashes 

    }
```

}

Comment: What is the definition of sndxMap? Where did the value "d" come from and where did you validate it not to be null? What error/crash do you get? Why not just use insert(std::make_pair(code, *it))?

Comment: could you please show more of ReplacementChooser class? definition and initialization and its instantiation somewhere in your code

Comment: Without more code, it's impossible to tell where the problem is. I'd guess either `d` is invalid, or `*it` isn't convertible to `std::string`

Comment: d in fact was not initialized. I accidentally deleted the initializer after the constructor for the type.